# Can't list files inside (a specific) folder

Tags: php, google-drive-api

So, I followed [Google Documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) and I got Google api to work, but it only lists the recent 10 files I opened on my Google Drive.

How to allow it to list files from **a specific folder** not all of them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Please edit your Q  and post relevant code you're working with to help others help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use this method https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes